# Decreasing data points by half via downsampling

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let say I have a `6x5` matrix (my actual data is way bigger)

A B C D E

1 5 7 2 3

2 1 9 8 5

3 1 2 3 1

4 1 3 4 2

5 2 9 0 1

6 5 3 4 3

I have to make a plot with A on the x-axis and B,C,D on the y-axis. If I want to reduce the data points by half (by averaging each adjacent pair of data points), how do I do it?  What if I want to decrease the points even further by averaging every five (or `n`) points?

I looked at the MATLAB help document but I'm still confused

**I got what I needed, thanks for the input guys, it really helped**

Comment: Actually a moving average does not decrease the number of points. What you want is not moving average but a kind of downsampling

Comment: What happens to last row if number of rows is odd?

Comment: What if I want to decrease the points even further by averaging every five points?

Comment: @user2909670: I added a flexible solution for any step size to my answer

Comment: Posted solutions for `n` averaged values, with the option to keep or retain the last `mod(size(M,1),n)` rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An even number of rows scenario is straightforward, using `mean` to do the work:

```
>> M = magic(4)
 M =
     16     2     3    13
      5    11    10     8
      9     7     6    12
      4    14    15     1
>> reshape(mean(reshape(M,2,[]),1),[],size(M,2))
ans =
   10.5000    6.5000    6.5000   10.5000
    6.5000   10.5000   10.5000    6.5000
```

For the odd number of rows scenario, let's say you want to retain the last row.  Here's a **general even/odd solution**:

```
>> M = magic(5) % 5 rows!
M =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
>> Mp = [M; repmat(M(end,:),mod(size(M,1),2),1)]; % replicate last row if odd
>> Mthin = reshape(mean(reshape(Mp,2,[]),1),[],size(Mp,2))
Mthin =
   20.0000   14.5000    4.0000   11.0000   15.5000
    7.0000    9.0000   16.0000   20.5000   12.5000
   11.0000   18.0000   25.0000    2.0000    9.0000
```

Alternatively, if you want to throw away the last row when encountered with an odd number of rows:

```
>> Mp = M(1:end-mod(size(M,1),2),:);
>> Mthin = reshape(mean(reshape(Mp,2,[]),1),[],size(Mp,2))
Mthin =
   20.0000   14.5000    4.0000   11.0000   15.5000
    7.0000    9.0000   16.0000   20.5000   12.5000
```

Now for **averaging `n` points**, retaining the average of the `mod(size(M,1),n)` last rows:

```
n = 5;
M = rand(972,5); % or whatever
p = mod(size(M,1),n);
r = repmat(mean(M(end-p+1:end,:),1),(p>0)*(n-p),1);
Mp = [M; r];
Mthin = reshape(mean(reshape(Mp,n,[]),1),[],size(Mp,2));
```

And for throwing out the last `mod(size(M,1),n)` rows:

```
Mp = M(1:end-mod(size(M,1),n),:);
Mthin = reshape(mean(reshape(Mp,n,[]),1),[],size(Mp,2));
```

Comment: The data I have has an odd number of rows and I have to average the data points using different n values so the the last option was perfect for what I needed to do. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

There you go:

```
M = [1 5 7 2 3
     2 1 9 8 5
     3 1 2 3 1
     4 1 3 4 2
     5 2 9 0 1
     6 5 3 4 3]; % data

>>result = (M(1:2:end-1,:) + M(2:2:end,:))/2;

result =

1.5000    3.0000    8.0000    5.0000    4.0000
3.5000    1.0000    2.5000    3.5000    1.5000
5.5000    3.5000    6.0000    2.0000    2.0000
```

Comment: Try this for odd rows.  You might need an `end-1` on the first part of the sum.

Comment: +! The question changed a lot huh?  But you got his first question nicely. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> A= magic(5) %some "random" data
A =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
    4    6   13   20   22
   10   12   19   21    3
   11   18   25    2    9

>>> B=(A(1:2:end-1,:)+A(2:2:end,:))/2
B =

   20.0000   14.5000    4.0000   11.0000   15.5000
    7.0000    9.0000   16.0000   20.5000   12.5000
```

Takes average of each pair of rows, ignores the last row if row count is not even.

And some general solution:

```
%input data data
X=randi(30,30,5)
step=7
%extend matrix, until size matches step (could be done faster using repmat)
while(mod(size(X,1),step)~=0)
    X(end+1,:)=X(end,:)
end
%Split data into segments of size "step"
C=mat2cell(X,repmat(step,floor(size(X,1)/step),1),size(X,2))
%Average over each segment:
AVG=cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)(mean(x,1)),C,'UniformOutput',false))
```

Comment: If you have more than one dangling row, you don't just want to replicate the last row since that will bias the mean for that block of `step` toward that row.  Also, I think you have the `while` condition fixed for a `step` of 4.